# Best cylinder water container shape to prevent heat loss

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

There's a workshop in my town and I want them to build me a boiling pot for homebrewing, my question is

What should be the proportions (radius to height) of the most efficient pot (best heat conservation)?

The pot must be made of stainless steel; I'm not sure how relevant is this but here it is

Comment: for a fixed volume, the shape of a cylinder that results in the least surface area is the cylinder that has height equal to twice the radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, heat transfer out of the pot must occur through the surface area of that pot.  The shape that holds a given volume but has the least surface area is a sphere, so the spherical shape will have the least area available for heat transfer to the environment.  However, I doubt that you want a spherical pot for boiling a liquid.  A more convenient shape is a cylinder, and the cylindrical shape that holds a given volume and also has the smallest surface area is a cylinder whose diameter equals its height.

Such a shape will lose temperature more slowly than other shapes, but there is another way to look at this problem.  Due to the small surface area of the above cylinder, there is also less surface area available for heat transfer when you are boiling the contents of the cylinder.  Thus, it easily seen that you may require more fuel and a longer "flame time" to boil the cylinder's contents.  The question then becomes, are you interested in minimizing the amount of fuel that it takes to boil the pot's contents, or are you interested in having the pot cool down as slowly as possible?

Comment: Actually, it's an interesting exercise in optimization to show that if you want *heating* (not just minimizing loss), then the requirement that incoming flux is larger than outgoing flux means there is no nontrivial extremum: the contact area with the flame must be maximal - such as heating coils or a flat thin pan over flame. The maximum surface area is only a solution if you are minimizing escaping heat, in which case your answer is right on the spot.

Comment: I was interested in keeping the pot hot, since I heat the wort to the desired temperature then I turn of the fire and let it rest for 20 minutes. Although I am interested in minimizing the amount of fuel for another step, how the pot proportions would change?

Comment: @GustavoAriasMéndez, if you are doing everything in the same pot, you will have to make a decision.  I don't see any way of minimizing fuel usage AND having the pot cool as slowly as possible, based solely on the shape of the pot.  If, on the other hand, you have a lot of surface area to decrease fuel consumption, and you cover the pot in some type of insulation after you turn off the flame, you may be able to get the results that you want.

Comment: Let me clarify, I wasn't clear, there are two different pots, I want the mashing one to conserve heat for as long as possible and the boiling one to minimize the amount of fuel

Comment: Then a shorter and wider boiling pot will help transfer heat into the boiling wort due to the relatively large surface area on the bottom of the pot that is exposed to the flame.  Once you pour the wort into the pot whose height equals its diameter, that pot will minimize heat transfer to the environment because of its minimal surface area.  Good luck, and don't drink too much at one time!

Answer (score 1):

there are two mechanisms of loosing heat here:
1. heat transfer from liquid (natural convection) through solid (conduction) and to the ambient air (natural convection)

2. Phase change - liquid layer on free surface will evaporate and absorb heat from the liquid.

You can do the following to reduce 1:

- minimize the surface area where heat transfer takes place, the smallest surface area per volume is in a sphere
- make the walls thicker to increase resistance in conduction therm (you can't really do anything about the convection - in principle the convective heat transfer on vertical walls should be higher than for horizontal walls due to difference in turbulence - natural convective cells go up-down because the gravity works in this direction, but the difference will be small imho)

You can do the following to reduce 2:

- make tha area of interface smaller ( amount of liquid that evaporates is proportional to it)
- ensure the path from liquid-air interface to ambient air is long, so the vapour must diffuse (which is very slow) before it gets swiped by the ambient air. (it's a still-air insulation)

You will get best results by ensuring thick walls and a cap for the pot.

edit:
you can also create cylinder with double walls - the air between solid will lower the heat loss through the walls significantly. That would be the most effective way, but probably difficult to make.